# Does Unbridled Growth provide two mana or one?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The new Aether Revolt card [Unbridled Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnbridled%20Growth%5d) reads:

> Enchanted land has "{T}: Add one mana of any color to your mana pool."

Does this mean the enchanted land provides two mana?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get two mana. If you enchant a basic land (mountain, forest, etc.) then it now essentially has two abilities. For example, if you enchant a mountain, then it's as if that mountain now reads:

> {T}: Add {R} to your mana pool.
>   {T}: Add one mana of any color to your mana pool.

So you can tap it for the first ability, *or* the second. You don't get to do both (just like you can't tap a creature to attack and use an activated ability).

Alternatively, you might enchant a non-basic land. For example, also from Aether Revolt is the land [Spire of Industry](http://mythicspoiler.com/aer/cards/spireofindustry.html). If you enchant it with Unbridled Growth, then it's as if the card now reads:

> {T}: Add ◊ to your mana pool.
>   {T}, Pay 1 life: Add one mana of any color to your mana pool. Activate this ability only if you control an artifact.
>   {T}: Add one mana of any color to your mana pool.